# Ruby on rails GRPC failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grpc

[image: snippet of grpc response]

I am calling my API via GRPC from rails monolith but I am getting this error on remote server. I had configured GRPC + Gruf to make API calls. Doe it mean request i not getting accepted?

Answer (score 0):

its in the response, error code 14.  That's the grpc error for "unavailable".  it means that for whatever reason, your call it not finding the server properly.

without more code, its impossible to say why this is happening.